# How can I check for equality within a row, amongst all indexes?

Tags: arrays, class, object

I'm lost and don't know where to begin. I'm testing the following condition, L=W=H on Package1's method and I want to call it into the Class Runtime's main method.

I created an array of objects already. But after that, I don't know how to utilize it or even if I have to. Again I'm completely lost!...thanks for your help.

I feel as if Coding is a young man's world!, Damn you Marine Corps!

---

```
public class Package1
{

    double length;
    double width;
    double height;

Package1(double a,double b, double c)
{
    length=a;
    width=b;
    height=c;
}
public void isCube()
{
    if(length==width && width==height)
        System.out.println("The box is a cube.");
    else
        System.out.println("Box is not a cube. ");

}

public class Runtime{
public static void main(String[] args){
Package1[] boxes = new Package1[rows];

    for(int j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++)
    {
        boxes[j] = new Package1(arr[j][0], arr[j][1], arr[j][2]);

    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.

```
for(int j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++)
{
    boxes[j] = new Package1(arr[j][0], arr[j][1], arr[j][2]);
    boxes[j].isCube(); // this is the line that you need
}
```

Any element in an array can be accessed by passing the index of the item into the brackets. For instance `boxes[0]` is the first element in the array. `boxes[ boxes.length - 1 ]` is the last element in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the time taken to help me and the answer. That worked just fined!